# ReactJS - componentDidUpdate() must update two values before one single action

Tags: reactjs, axios

In my ReactJS component, I perform a token request to an external API, and then must pass that token, as well as my userId, as arguments to an `axios` request. This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Credentials from './spotify-auth.js'
import './Spotify.css'


class SpotifyAuth extends Component {  
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAuthenticatedWithSpotify: false,
      menu: this.props.userId.menu
    };
    this.state.handleRedirect = this.handleRedirect.bind(this);
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
      this.getFeatures(); // <------- axios method, see below
  }

  generateRandomString(length) {
    let text = '';
    const possible =
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
    } 

  getHashParams() {
    const hashParams = {};
    const r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g;
    const q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    let e = r.exec(q);
    while (e) {
      hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
      e = r.exec(q);
    }
    return hashParams;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
    const params = this.getHashParams();

    const access_token = params.access_token;
    const state = params.state;
    const storedState = localStorage.getItem(Credentials.stateKey);
    localStorage.setItem('spotifyAuthToken', access_token);
    localStorage.getItem('spotifyAuthToken');

    if (window.localStorage.getItem('authToken')) {
      this.setState({ isAuthenticatedWithSpotify: true });
    };
    if (access_token && (state == null || state !== storedState)) {
      alert('Click "ok" to finish authentication with Spotify');
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem(Credentials.stateKey);
    }
    // DO STUFF WITH ACCEES TOKEN HERE
    this.props.onConnectWithSpotify(access_token); 
  };
```

The problem I was facing was that `axios` method was being called before I had my userId and spotifyToken states and props defined.

So I applied the following defensive programming solution:

```
  getFeatures(event) {
    const {userId, spotifyToken} = this.props
    if (!spotifyToken || !userId) {   // <-------------- HERE
      return;
    }
    const data = {
      spotify_token: this.props.spotifyToken
    };
    var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/features/${userId}/${spotifyToken}`;
    axios.post(url, data, {headers: headers})
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
      });
  };

  handleRedirect(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.createMessage('You linked your Spotify account!', 'success');
    // get client features at authentication
    const params = this.getHashParams();
    const access_token = params.access_token;
    console.log(access_token);

    const state = this.generateRandomString(16);
    localStorage.setItem(Credentials.stateKey, state);

    let url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';
    url += '?response_type=token';
    url += '&client_id=' + encodeURIComponent(Credentials.client_id);
    url += '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(Credentials.scope);
    url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(Credentials.redirect_uri);
    url += '&state=' + encodeURIComponent(state);
    window.location = url; 
  };

  render() {
      return (
        <div className="button_container">
        <h1 className="title is-3"><font color="#C86428">{"Welcome"}</font></h1>
            <div className="Line" /><br/>
              <button className="sp_button" onClick={(event) => this.handleRedirect(event)}>
                <strong>LINK YOUR SPOTIFY ACCOUNT</strong>
              </button>
        </div>
      )
  }
}
export default SpotifyAuth;
```

Now I don't get wrong calls with undefined values, but axios method is being called twice, one at each value update, which is also undesired.

---

> If I put `getFeatures()` inside `componentDidUpdate()`, and don't user the conditional, I get:

1. Failed request where both values are undefined
2. Then it updates `userId` and I get undefined only for `spotifyToken`.
3. Finally, when I click the button it works, both values are updated, but then request is sent twice.

   ---

> Following the Single Responsibility Principle, I have also tried the following solution:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { spotifyToken, userId } = this.props;
  if (spotifyToken && userId && (spotifyToken !== prevProps.spotifyToken || userId !== prevProps.userId)) {
    this.getFeatures();
  }
}
```

But it does not work.

---

How do I fix this?

Comment: can't you just put your axios request in componentDidMount, just need to make sure to check both the token and user id exist? When you do the redirect (window.location = url), that should unmount the component right?

Comment: they do exist, but axios requests are being called beforehand. Yes, I think it unmounts the component

Comment: I'll just put what I'm thinking in an answer since it's hard to put code here.

Comment: sure go ahead, thanks

Comment: If I put `getFeatures()` inside `componentDidUpdate()`, and don't user the conditional, I get a failed request where both values are undefined, then it updates `userId` and throws undefined only for token. finally, when I click the button it works, but then request is sent twice.

Comment: check both the token and userId to make sure they exist before calling getFeatures()? I was going to put in that code, but i see you are almost where I was thinking of trying.